# Local variable in makefile is not expanded correctly

Tags: function, makefile, variable-expansion

I have the following function in makefile:

```
define INSTALL_SCRIPT
SRC_DIR = $(ROOT)\src
cd $(SRC_DIR)
$(SRC_DIR)\stage.bat
endef
```

I also echo the steps, so here's the output of the above snippet:

```
$SRC_DIR = C:\project_root\src
'SRC_DIR' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
$cd
C:\project_root
\stage.bat
'\stage.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

It seems that in assignment statement the value is expanded correctly but then `$(SRC_DIR)` gives an error. Then `cd` goes to one directory up (and not `src`), then when I need to execute the batch file, `$(SRC_DIR)`'s value seems to be empty.

Comment: The assignment is neither valid `cmd` nor `sh`; the error message indicates you tried to use it in a recipe which you are not showing. In `cmd`, variable assignments use `set`; in `sh`, you cant't have spaces around the equals sign.

Comment: It's actually more deeply flawed than just that -- if it's a macro which is expanded in a recipe, then: `SRC_DIR` will be set on the first recipe line, and won't be visible in the second line.    Even if you did concatenate the lines, it will expand `$(SRC_DIR)` when it is trying to expand the macro as a makefile variable, so the resulting bash command will be `cd `...

Comment: Ahh, never mind -- it's a windows script...   I believe the recipe line thing holds -- the `$` definately doesn't work though...   You might need `%SRC_DIR%`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to do this from a recipe context, you would need to do it as follows:

```
define INSTALL_SCRIPT
   set SRC_DIR=$(ROOT)\\src & \
   cd %SRC_DIR% & \
   %SRC_DIR%\\stage.bat
endef

sometarget:
   @$(INSTALL_SCRIPT)
```

You need the `\` at the end of each line to concatinate them into a single recipe line (other wise the variable you set will fall out of context when the first recipe line's shell terminates).   You seem to be using windows so I believe you need to use the `%varname%` syntax to refer to the variables.   Notice that `$(ROOT)` is a makefile variable in this case, so it still uses the `$` syntax.   (Note that if you were in bash you would need to use `$$` to refer to shell variables).  You also need to double the `\\` in directory names, as make will interpret the first slash as an escape, and then pass a single slash to cmd.

Note that my windows machine doesn't have make installed on it, so I couldn't test the above, so it's quite possible I missed something.

Comment: `cmd` doesn't understand `;` `&` is used instead

Comment: Thanks.   As you can tell I'm more of a bash person...   Hopefully that runs.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to guess what is make's SHELL on Windows. If there's any `sh.exe` in PATH then gmake will use it instead of cmd.

Comment: Note to OP: as per @Matt's comment: If it's using the `sh` then the slashes in the directory name are wrong, it would need to use `;`, and `$(SRC_DIR)` would be treated as a command instead of a variable...    It would be a completely different answer...